# Searching logs, outputting lines before and after match

Tags: python, list, slice

I am trying to make a script that lets me search through all the text files in a folder to find string(s) and write a choosen number of lines before and after the line where the string I am looking for.

My problem is that when I put a variable in the slice method, I am only getting the number of lines before the match. When I test with plain numbers( [1:6] ) it works.

What am I missing?

Any suggestions for improvement is also very appreciated.

---

What I am looking for(datafile):

> ```
> 12345
> ```

What I want to be written to the result file:

> ```
> 2 elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget d
> 3 olor. Aenean massa. 
> 4 Cum sociis natoque 12345penatibus et m
> 5 agnis dis parturient montes, nasc
> 6 etur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
> ```

The text I am searching through:

> ```
> 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
> 2 elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget d
> 3 olor. Aenean massa. 
> 4 Cum sociis natoque 12345 penatibus et m
> 5 agnis dis parturient montes, nasc
> 6 etur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
> 7 massa quis enim. Donec pede just
> 8 o, fringilla vel, 
> 9 aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
> ```

---

The code

```
import os 

search_folder = r'E:\stash\Logs'
datafile = r'E:\stash\variable.txt' 
resultsFile = r'E:\stash\results.txt'
nbrOfLinesOver = 3
nbrOfLinesUnder = 2


# Finds all the log files in the directory that needs to be searched through

def findFiles(folder):

    log_files = []
    for files in os.listdir(search_folder):
        log_files.append(files)
    return log_files

# Finds the strings I want to search for

def searchFor(datafile):

    stringToFind = open(datafile,'r')
    data = stringToFind.readline()
    data = str(data).split()
    map(str.strip,data)
    stringToFind.close()
    return data

#Searches through the text files to find the strings and outputs the number of lines defined under and over the match

def findLogData(log_Files, searchForData, folderPath, resultsFile):
    resultFile = open(resultsFile, "w")
    lineCounter = 0
    logLines = [] 

    for file in log_Files:
        datalookUp = open(folderPath + "\\" + file,'r', encoding='UTF-8')
        log = datalookUp.readlines()

        for line in log:
            lineCounter += 1 
            logLines.append(str(line))            

            for stringToFind in searchForData:
                if stringToFind in line: 
                    slinceStart = lineCounter - nbrOfLinesOver
                    slinceEnd = lineCounter + nbrOfLinesUnder
                    resultFile.writelines(logLines[slinceStart:slinceEnd])

    resultFile.close()
    datalookUp.close()


FilesToSearch = findFiles(search_folder)
stringsToFind = searchFor(datafile)
findLogData(FilesToSearch,stringsToFind,search_folder,resultsFile)
```

EDIT:
I am also having problems with the searchFor. Right now, I have to put everything I want to search for in one line. When I have all the strings I want to search for listed in the text file I get "\n" in the list as well.
That is also the reason for the map function. It's code I forgot to remove when I tried to get rid of it after a suggestion I found on a forum but I couldn't get strip to remove the linebreaks.

Comment: In ```searchfor()``` you haven't assigned the return value of ```map``` to anything.

Comment: ```logLines``` appears to be superfluous - just work with ```log```, you don't need to create a separate list to hold the lines you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logLines` appears to be superfluous - just work with `log`, you don't need to create a separate list to hold the lines you are interested in.

I've modified your function leaving original lines commented with `##` -  and a single `#` to simplify my file path *construction*.

```
def findLogData(log_Files, searchForData, folderPath, resultsFile, span = (3,2)):
##    resultFile = open(resultsFile, "w")
##    lineCounter = 0
##    logLines = [] 

##        datalookUp = open(folderPath + "\\" + file,'r', encoding='UTF-8')
##        log = datalookUp.readlines()
    nbrOfLinesOver, nbrOfLinesUnder = span
    with open(resultsFile, 'w') as resultFile:
        for filename in log_Files:
            #filename = folderPath + "\\" + file
            with open(filename,'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                log = f.readlines()

            for lineCounter, line in enumerate(log):
    ##            lineCounter += 1 
    ##            logLines.append(str(line))            

                for stringToFind in searchForData:
                    if stringToFind in line: 
                        slinceStart = min(0, lineCounter - nbrOfLinesUnder)
                        slinceEnd = max(len(log), lineCounter + nbrOfLinesOver + 1)
##                        resultFile.writelines(logLines[slinceStart:slinceEnd])
                        resultFile.writelines(log[slinceStart:slinceEnd])

##    resultFile.close()
##    datalookUp.close()
```

---

And with the original lines deleted:

```
def findLogData(log_Files, searchForData, folderPath, resultsFile, span = (3,2)):
    nbrOfLinesOver, nbrOfLinesUnder = span
    with open(resultsFile, 'w') as resultFile:
        for filename in log_Files:

            #filename = folderPath + "\\" + file
            with open(filename,'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                log = f.readlines()

            for lineCounter, line in enumerate(log):
                for stringToFind in searchForData:
                    if stringToFind in line: 
                        slinceStart = min(0, lineCounter - nbrOfLinesUnder)
                        slinceEnd = max(len(log), lineCounter + nbrOfLinesOver + 1)
                        resultFile.writelines(log[slinceStart:slinceEnd])
```

---

If all the files in the search folder are log files, you don't really need `findFiles()` - `os.listdir()` returns a list so

```
FilesToSearch = os.listdir(search_folder)
```

I would probably have FilesToSearch contain the *whole* filepath for each log file.

```
FilesToSearch  = []
for fname in os.listdir(search_folder):
    FilesToSearch.append(search_folder + '\\' + fname)
```

or

```
import os.path
for fname in os.listdir(search_folder):
    FilesToSearch.append(os.path.join(search_folder,fname))
```

---

It looks like you expect to use the first line of `datafile`.  I prefer to open files using a context manager ([`with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)) so the file will always get closed:

```
def searchFor(datafile):
    with open(datafile,'r') as f:
        data = f.readline()
        data = data.split()
        data = [thing.strip() for thing in data]
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you! I've removed the find_files and used your suggestion. Others have pointed out the same, using a context manager, so I have edited my code to use that.  
I also see others are using min and max to define the slice as well. When I use it, I get the entire content of the file listed. Not just the line with the string I am looking for and the number of lines before and after. Using just slinceStart = lineCounter - nbrOfLinesOver works.

Comment: Oh, another thing. I remember why I have map in the  searchFor method, it's left over code from a problem I couldn't solve. I can't do a lot of writing or text formatting in comments, so I'll edit my problem in my question post.

Comment: @SuperKyllingen - ```min``` and ```max``` are used to prevent specifying an index that is not valid. If that is not working when you use it then something else must be going wrong - it works when I use it - you could try printing ```lineCounter```, ```slinceStart``` and ```slinceEnd``` to try and diagnose it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is occurring because `logLines` only contains till the line that contains the string, it does not contain any line after that (as those have not yet been read).

Also , one thing to note is that when slicing even if the slice boundary is out of bounds, it will not throw an error , instead it will take all possible elements in the range and return that. Example -

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> lst[3:123]
[4]
```

You should rather than storing the entire log file in the memory in `logLines` only store the required amount. Also, it would be adviced that using `with` would be better as it would handle closing the file for you. Example code -

```
def findLogData(log_Files, searchForData, folderPath, resultsFile):
    with open(resultsFile, "w") as resultFile:
        lineCounter = 0

        for file in log_Files:
            with open(folderPath + "\\" + file,'r', encoding='UTF-8') as datalookUp:
                logLines = []
                flag = False
                remLines = 0
                for line in log:
                    if remLines > 0:
                        resultsFile.write(line)
                        remLines -= 1
                    logLines.append(line)
                    if len(logLines) > nbrOfLinesOver + 1:
                        logLines.pop(0)

                    for stringToFind in searchForData:
                        if stringToFind in line:
                            resultsFile.writelines(logLines)
                            remLines = nbrOfLinesUnder
```

Comment: it missing the line numbers

Comment: line number? According to OP's example, that is part of the file itself, if so it would come in the result file as well. If not, the original OP's code would not write the line number either, so not sure if OP really wants that.

Comment: Thanks! They are quite large. Anywhere from a few kbs to almost a gig. I definitely need to make some handling of the data so I don't store everything in the memory.

I don't quite understand what your code does from just reading it, so I will have to run it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the task (simplified a bit to get at the important bit - getting x lines of context before/after matches read in from file):

**test.log**

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
2 elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget d
3 olor. Aenean massa.
4 Cum sociis natoque 12345 penatibus et m
5 agnis dis parturient montes, nasc
6 etur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
7 massa quis enim. Donec pede just
8 o, fringilla vel,
9 aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
```

**test.py**

```
def get_lines(file_name):
    lines = None
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines

def print_matches_in_file(search_str, file_name, num_lines_context=0):
    """
    Will print out matching lines as well as num_lines_context before and
    num_lines_context after
    """
    lines = get_lines(file_name)
    if lines:
        num_lines = len(lines)
        for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
            if search_str in line:
                start_line = max([0, idx - num_lines_context])
                end_line = min([num_lines, idx + num_lines_context + 1])
                print ''.join(lines[start_line: end_line])

print_matches_in_file("12345", "test.log", num_lines_context=2)
```

which, when run, outputs:

```
2 elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget d
3 olor. Aenean massa.
4 Cum sociis natoque 12345 penatibus et m
5 agnis dis parturient montes, nasc
6 etur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat
```

This reads the entire log file into memory at once before searching for the matching substring which may or may not be appropriate depending on the size of your file.